# GWT Compilation Fails using maven but not eclipse - NoSuchMethodError UiBinderWriter.<init>

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, gwt, uibinder, nosuchmethoderror

I'm running into an exception compiling a GWT project using maven, but it's working in eclipse.  I've spend the last few hours googling and searching StackOverflow, but while a couple results were relevant, none fit my situation.

Environment:

- OSX 10.10.1
- Java 1.7.0_67 64 bit
- GWT 2.7.0
- GWTP 1.3.1
- GAE 1.9.17
- Maven 3.2.3

I can run the project in eclipse using Super Dev Mode, and it works fine.  I can use the Eclipse GWT plugin to compile the project - it completes successfully.  But if I try to compile via the terminal using `mvn clean compile gwt:compile`, I get the following error:

```
[INFO] Compiling module com.example.foo.Foo
[INFO]    [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
[INFO] com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit.
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.translateException(JVisitor.java:121)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:296)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:128)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement.traverse(JDeclarationStatement.java:49)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContext.traverse(JModVisitor.java:95)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemove(JModVisitor.java:351)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:92)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:149)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:145)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:83)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:600)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.traverse(JMethod.java:569)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.mainLoop(UnifyAst.java:1505)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.exec(UnifyAst.java:870)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$Precompiler.unifyJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1305)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$Precompiler.constructJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1038)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$Precompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:954)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.MonolithicJavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(MonolithicJavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:303)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:38)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:286)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:206)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:158)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:120)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:127)
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderWriter.<init>(Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/typeinfo/JClassType;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/typeinfo/TypeOracle;Lcom/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/MortalLogger;Lcom/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/FieldManager;Lcom/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/messages/MessagesWriter;Lcom/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/DesignTimeUtils;Lcom/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/UiBinderContext;ZZLjava/lang/String;)V
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator.generateOnce(UiBinderGenerator.java:187)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator.generate(UiBinderGenerator.java:135)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:760)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:160)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:79)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:276)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:87)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createStaticRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:485)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:443)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleMagicMethodCall(UnifyAst.java:576)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.endVisit(UnifyAst.java:306)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:248)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
[INFO]  ... 35 more
[INFO]       [ERROR] at com_gwtplatform_mvp_client_DesktopGinjector_DesktopGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java(91): GWT.create(ApplicationView$Binder.class)
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall
[INFO]       [ERROR] at com_gwtplatform_mvp_client_DesktopGinjector_DesktopGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java(91): Object created = GWT.create(ApplicationView$Binder.class)
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement
[INFO]       [ERROR] at com_gwtplatform_mvp_client_DesktopGinjector_DesktopGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java(90): {
[INFO]   Object created = GWT.create(ApplicationView$Binder.class);
[INFO]   assert created instanceof ApplicationView$Binder;
[INFO]   ApplicationView$Binder result = (ApplicationView$Binder) created;
[INFO]   this.memberInject_Key$type$com$example$foo$client$application$ApplicationView$Binder$_annotation$$none$$(result);
[INFO]   return result;
[INFO] }
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock
[INFO]       [ERROR] at com_gwtplatform_mvp_client_DesktopGinjector_DesktopGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java(90): {
[INFO]   Object created = GWT.create(ApplicationView$Binder.class);
[INFO]   assert created instanceof ApplicationView$Binder;
[INFO]   ApplicationView$Binder result = (ApplicationView$Binder) created;
[INFO]   this.memberInject_Key$type$com$example$foo$client$application$ApplicationView$Binder$_annotation$$none$$(result);
[INFO]   return result;
[INFO] }
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody
[INFO]       [ERROR] at com_gwtplatform_mvp_client_DesktopGinjector_DesktopGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java(90): public ApplicationView$Binder get_Key$type$com$example$foo$client$application$ApplicationView$Binder$_annotation$$none$$();
[INFO] 
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.013 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-12-06T20:28:36-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I used the GWTP plugin to generate a basic project for use on Google App Engine, and had to tweak a number of things to get it so that it would work locally  and push to app engine.  It compiled fine at the time, eclipse or maven.  I made a few more modifications, mostly messing with UI and GWT Logging, testing all the while in Super Dev Mode, and it worked fine.  works fine now.  Since it wasn't done, I didn't try to upload to GAE.

Research:

One involved [inherited modules](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/google-web-toolkit/14a9qk5rcd/error-compiling-a-ui-binder-file-with-2-7) that were overriding the GWT UIBinder implementation, but I have added no inherits or dependencies from the archetype I used to generate it.  Plus, it works through eclipse / SuperDevMode.
The [other](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plugin-eclipse/Vy1wgknpdtU) was about getting compilation to work in eclipse, and I may have used it to get eclipse working when I first worked on the project a week ago.  But it works in eclipse, but not via maven command line.

I've tried removing various modules not required by gwt/gwtp and have had no luck.  I specified a gwt-user and gwt-dev import version, nothing.  Always I get that same error, and it's driving me mad!  I just can't figure out why it won't compile with 'normal' maven.

Comment: If some dependency "shadows" the `com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderWriter` class, then it must be a classpath ordering issue. Either you changed your Maven version and it orders dependencies differently, or you changed dependency declaration order in your `pom.xml`. Try using "open type" in Eclipse to locate the dependency that contains the offending out-of-date class and try to update that dependency with one that's compatible with GWT 2.7 (and/or reorder your POM)

Comment: You were right - it was dependency order.  I don't remember changing it, but I fixed it by reordering dependencies.  Namely, I moved gwt-user to the front of the list, and the problem went away.  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that one of my other dependencies was 'shadowing' the UIBinder I needed, as thomas-broyer pointed out.  I'm not sure when it changed, I don't remember moving any dependencies around.  Perhaps it was a transitive dependency somewhere.  In any case I solved it by...

Adding/moving the gwt-user dependency to the front of the list.  Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

GWTP overrides the UiBinderGenerator to allow Gin to works with the UiBinder. Change the version of GWTP to 1.4-SNAPSHOT (1.4 should be released really soon!), it should fix the problem, as we moved the UiBinderGenerator to an extension instead of being part of the core MVP framework. The reason it's working with Eclipse is probably a classpath ordering issue, like Thomas Broyer pointed out.

Comment: In this case it wasn't GWTP related, but it's definitely something to look out for